# Find the Sum of Cumulative Proability in Excel

Tags: excel, probability, cumulative-distribution-function

Im wondering how I would calculate the Sum of a Cumulative Probability in Excel?

I have attached the column of values that I am working with. Any help is appreciated

[image]

I have tried finding the mean/average of the values and then std deviation, then using the norm distribution function and then sum those values but it doesn't seem to be creating the right value.

Comment: So what mathematical / statistical theory are you applying?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NORM.DIST(x,mean,standard_dev,cumulative)` which allows you to specify the mean and the standard deviation. If the last argument is `TRUE` it returns the cumulative probability. Obviously, *under the assumption, the distribution of your data corresponds to the Normal Distribution*. If you are not sure about that, then you need to run a [normality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test#:%7E:text=A%20normality%20test%20is%20used,a%20normally%20distributed%20sample%20population.) that will confirm that first (anyway most natural phenomenons are distributed as Normal).

For the mean, you can use the `AVERAGE` function, and for the Standard Deviation `STDEV.S`.

So on cell `D4` put the following formula to calculate the cumulative probability for `0.25`:

```
=NORM.DIST(D3,D1,D2, TRUE)
```

[image: saple excel file]

So if your data correspond to a Normal Distribution, then the cumulative probability for `0.25` will be `0.361494`.